# How to append in jquery after check div is not hidden?

Tags: jquery, css

How to append dynamic div in jquery after check that div is not hidden.

```
$('#tbl_tasks').append(' <div class="tblrow tbldata" style="display:none;" id="' + so_no + '" onclick="viewfun(this);" ><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol1"> ' + obj.task_date + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol2"> ' + so_no + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol3"> ' + customer_name + ' </div><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol4"> ' + obj.customer_id + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol5"> ' + obj.tot_emp + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol6">' + emp_total_hours + '</div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol7"> ' + real_value + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol8"> ' + po_value + ' </div> </div>');
```

this is dynamically created div and append with that parent div.
i want to check if tbcol4 div is hidden mean not want to append. If visible mean want to append.

Comment: `$('div.tbcol4').filter(':visible').append(html)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:visible` selector for this:

`$(selector).is(':visible')` and then append

```
$('#tbl_tasks').filter(function(){
   return $(this).find('.tbcol4').is(':visible');
}).append('<div class="tblrow tbldata" style="display:none;" id="' + so_no + '" onclick="viewfun(this);" ><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol1"> ' + obj.task_date + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol2"> ' + so_no + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol3"> ' + customer_name + ' </div><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol4"> ' + obj.customer_id + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol5"> ' + obj.tot_emp + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol6">' + emp_total_hours + '</div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol7"> ' + real_value + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol8"> ' + po_value + ' </div> </div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector here:

```
if($('.tbcol4 ').is(":visible") {
    $('#tbl_tasks').append(' <div class="tblrow tbldata" style="display:none;" id="' + so_no + '" onclick="viewfun(this);" ><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol1"> ' + obj.task_date + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol2"> ' + so_no + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol3"> ' + customer_name + ' </div><div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol4"> ' + obj.customer_id + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol5"> ' + obj.tot_emp + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol6">' + emp_total_hours + '</div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol7"> ' + real_value + ' </div> <div class="tblcell tblreportcell tbcol8"> ' + po_value + ' </div> </div>');
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. some time its not only that column. So want to check each div is visible then append particular div to parent div.. Help me.

Comment: @user3048072 Please edit your question to elaborate more on it with what is your requirements and your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function in conjunction with the [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector:

```
if($('.tbcol4').is(':visible'))
{
    // Do your append here...
}
```